# EmberJS "this" changed in promise (find) callback

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, rsvp-promise

When I want to fetch an account from the server in an controller action e.g:

```
account: false,

actions: {

    // When the oAuth popup returns this method will be called
    fetchUser: function(id)
    {           
        // Get the account from the server
        this.store.find('account', id).then(function(account)
        {
            this.set('account', account);
        }, function(error)
        {
            console.log('error', error);
        });

    },
}
```

It throws an error because "this" on the line `this.set('account', account)` is no longer the controller. How can I set "account" on the controller now from within this promise callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
account: false,

actions: {

// When the oAuth popup returns this method will be called
fetchUser: function(id)
{           
    // Get the account from the server
    this.store.find('account', id).then(function(account)
    {
        this.set('account', account);
    }.bind(this), function(error)
    {
        console.log('error', error);
    });

},
```

}

Fixed it! added .bind(this) :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is not EmberJS doing that, that's just the way Javascript scopes work.

The `this` keyword's scope is the function in which it is used.

Here's a link that will help you understand this..

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

I also suggest watching Crockford's videos on Javascript, he explains this and the workaround for what you're trying to do.

Here's a link to his videos..

http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the typical

```
var self = this;
```

Before entering the function that changes the scope of `this` and using `self` instead of `this` from within the function.

```
self.set('account', account);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for ember object. `var self = this;` will throw an error. You would need to set it like this `self:this.` as an object property assignment. But that wouldn't get you anywhere because you would need to used "this" to reference it anyway `this.self`